# Software for network switch

Tags: windows, linux, networking

I want to connect a pc, call it pc1, to another pc, call it pc2. I want to use pc1 to send pc2's traffic to the Internet or forwarding it simply, 
Knowing that pc2 will be the one that has the  web browser and the traffic out of pc2 will be encrypted and address the server not pc1 
Is there any software that may run on pc1 just to forward pc2's traffic.
Please note that I will take care of any other software to make this happen, I just need pc1 to forward pc2's traffic.

Note:

- pc1 is running Windows
- pc2 is running Linux

Comment: What operating system would pc1 and pc2 be using?

Comment: Pc1  windows pc2 Linux